# Sending variable from php to js file not working

Tags: 7

I've followed this : [how to send variable from .php file to .js file?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/4482/how-to-send-variable-from-php-file-to-js-file-in-drupal-7).

But following my code isn't working

What I want to do is whenever anybody logs in I want to send the login/password to browser javascript which will send it to another server.

It's only for a test case and not for production environment.

**Details**:

cyberoam.js

```
(function($) {
  Drupal.behaviors.cyberoam = {
    attach: function (context, settings) {

        alert(Drupal.settings.cyberoam.login) //on commenting this below alert works

      alert("hello");
    }
  };

})(jQuery);
```

In the cyberoam.module

```
function cyberoam_from_alter_submit(&$form, &$form_state)
{
     $username = $form_state['values']['name'];
     $password = $form_state['values']['pass'];

     dsm($username.':'.$password); //working fine

     drupal_add_js(array('cyberoam' => array('login' => $username )), 'setting');
}
```

What could be the problem? I've read same solution in multiple places but mine isn't working. In the Firebug console it shows TypeError: Drupal.settings.cyberoam is undefined

Comment: array('type' => 'setting') instead of 'setting', but after submit you will be redirected and thats why your variable is undefined

Comment: More information on this can be found here: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/36448/drupal-add-js-setting-not-being-set-on-form-submit

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't set the values in the submit hook, you should use [hook_init()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_init/7).

In the submit hook you should set a variable ( `variable_set("name", "value")` ) and read it in the `hook_init` using `variable_get("name", "dafault_value")`;

On the other hand, you should **NEVER** add the password in js variables. It's a huge security risk.

Comment: It's a test case. I want both login/passwd to be sent to the javascript. hook_init is called before hook_submit during which I'd not have collected the passwd

Comment: Probably you can use `preprocess_page` instead of hook_init

Comment: hook_init is called first but after hook_submit is called, the page will refresh. So if you save you values in variables using variable_set() they will be available when page refreshes. Hope it makes sense.